# Excel VBA IF then IF statement

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement, msgbox

I am using an "If Then If msgbox vbYesno" Statement and I am not sure how to get out correctly of it (I know Goto is not clean).

Can someone tell me what my mistake is? I did not find anyone using something similar.

```
Sub IF_THEN_IF()

If Sheet1.Range("A1").Value > 500 Then
    If MsgBox("A1 > 500, Is this correct", vbYesNo, "Amount of Lines") = vbYes Then
        Range("H11").FormulaR1C1 = "My Formula"
    Else
        GoTo Jump
    End If
Else

Jump:    
    Range("H11").FormulaR1C1 = "I have Jumped"

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: If you describe what you are trying to achieve, not just your code, perhaps we can come up with a better solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can leave your procedure if you're not going to "jump", jumping otherway:

```
Sub IF_THEN_IF()
    If Sheet1.Range("A1").Value > 500 Then
        If MsgBox("A1 > 500, Is this correct", vbYesNo, "Amount of Lines") = vbYes Then
            Range("H11").FormulaR1C1 = "My Formula"
            Exit Sub
        End If
   End If
   'Jump
    Range("H11").FormulaR1C1 = "I have Jumped"
End Sub
```

Another option is use boolean variable:

```
Sub IF_THEN_IF()
    Dim Jump as Boolean
    Jump = Sheet1.Range("A1").Value <= 500
    If Not Jump Then Jump = MsgBox("A1 > 500, Is this correct", vbYesNo, "Amount of Lines") <> vbYes
    If Jump Then
        Range("H11").FormulaR1C1 = "I have Jumped"
    Else
        Range("H11").FormulaR1C1 = "My Formula"
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

This answer is in response to the comment you made on the answer of Vityaya.

Turn the code from `Jump` into a sub routine and call it as necessary.

```
Sub IF_THEN_IF()

With Sheet1 

    If .Range("A1").Value > 500 Then

        Dim res as Variant
        res = MsgBox("A1 > 500, Is this correct", vbYesNo, "Amount of Lines")

        If res = vbYes Then
            .Range("H11").FormulaR1C1 = "My Formula"
        Else
            Jump
        End If

    Else   

        Jump

    End If

End Sub

Sub Jump()
   'code here
End Sub
```

Comment: Now I see what the OP wanted.

Comment: Yeah that quite the kind of solution I was expecting (more clear/clean) eventhough I was hoping to stay in the same Sub

Answer (score 0):

A possible option is like this:

```
Sub IfThenElse()

    With Sheet1
        If .Range("A1").value > 500 Then
            If MsgBox("A1 > 500, Is this correct", vbYesNo, "Amount of Lines") = vbYes Then
                .Range("H11") = "My Formula"
            Else
                .Range("H11") = "I have Jumped"
            End If
        Else
            .Range("H11") = "I have Jumped"
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

You have two embedded ifs. That's all. In the answer of [Excel VBA IF then IF statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46771236/excel-vba-if-then-if-statement/46771712#46771712) @Scott Holtzmann, you may see how to avoid writing "I have jumped" twice, by following the [DRY method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

Comment: as a note to OP. The outer `Else` and line below can be totally removed without effect on the syntax as well.

Comment: I already came up with this but my issue is that the line "I have jumped" as to come if the msgbox is vbNo and if Range("A1").value < 500. 
But the issue is that the "I have jumped" part is really long in my real Code. and I wouldn t like to write it twice. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `AND` operator

```
Sub IF_THEN_IF()    
If Sheet1.Range("A1").Value > 500 And _
   MsgBox("A1 > 500, Is this correct", vbYesNo, "Amount of Lines") = vbYes Then

    Range("H11").FormulaR1C1 = "My Formula"

Else

    Range("H11").FormulaR1C1 = "I have Jumped"

End Sub
```

Comment: But not same code, as this code will always ask with message box, regardless of >500 or not. VB doesn't have short circuited And operator.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman don't mention it, it will attract competition. Oops missed the `End If` line, but nvm... :D

Comment: @LS_ᴅᴇᴠ, may be OP wants to confirm everything. :p

Comment: @Rosetta Maybe, but it is not what original code does.